# What is the principle of randomly selecting positions to swap in the shuffle function

Tags: python, fisher-yates-shuffle

Fisher–Yates shuffle means that we take the last number from the selected segment every time and swap it with the previously randomly selected number, iterate continuously, and finally achieve random shuffling.The code for the official Shuffle in python3.6 is as follows

```
     _int = int
     for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
          # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
          j = _int(random() * (i+1))
          x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Why not just pick the global locations and swap？

Comment: "then the position to be exchanged is always 0 every time the random selection is made" - no it's not.

Comment: what's the reason for `_int = int`?

Comment: @Barmar: It's a microoptimization to avoid some global lookups. Not as impactful these days due to global variable caching optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random()` is a float in the range `[0, 1)`. When you multiply that by `i+1`, you get a float in the range `[0, i+1)`. When you convert that to an integer, you get an integer in the range `[0, i]`.

Of course, you could just use `random.randint(0, i)`. And `reverse(range(1, len(x))` can be simplified to `range(len(x)-1, 0, -1)`.

Comment: The code does in fact avoid using `random()` in the usual code path - what the questioner posted was an alternate code path used if the caller provides their own `random` argument. It uses `randbelow` in the usual case. (As for "simplifying" `reversed(range(1, len(x))`, that's a matter of opinion. I personally find the `reversed` version much clearer.)